# Changing TabStripPlacement on ButtonClick

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, tabcontrol

I am new to wpf and I would like to change my TapStripPlacement on ButtonClick.
I tried finding the solution by myself but couldnt do it.
I Would be Very Happy over a fast solution.

This is my Code:

```
    <Window x:Class="Pages.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="TabControl" Height="350" Width="525">


    <Window.Resources>

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Foreground" Color="#FF9531b1"></SolidColorBrush>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Background" Color="Transparent"></SolidColorBrush>

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="TabItemControlTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
            <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{StaticResource Foreground}" BorderThickness="0" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                    <Border.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Background}"/>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Background}" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Background}" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Border.Style>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding HeaderStringFormat}" ContentSource="Header" HorizontalAlignment="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Foreground}"></Setter>
                <Setter TargetName="Content" Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="White"></Setter>
                <Setter TargetName="Content" Property="TextBlock.FontWeight" Value="Heavy"></Setter>
            </Trigger>

            <MultiTrigger >
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions >
                    <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"></Condition>
                    <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="false"></Condition>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter TargetName="Content" Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Foreground}"></Setter>
                <Setter TargetName="Content" Property="TextBlock.FontWeight" Value="Heavy"></Setter>
            </MultiTrigger>

        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

        </ControlTemplate>

</Window.Resources>


    <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
        <Button x:Name="btnTop">Top</Button>
        <Button Name="btnRight">Right</Button>
        <Button Name="btnBottom">Bottom</Button>
        <Button Name="btnLeft">Left</Button>
    </StackPanel>

    <TabControl Grid.Column="0"  x:Name="MyControl" Height="200"
                    Background="Transparent"
                    BorderThickness="0,1,0,0"
                    BorderBrush="{StaticResource Foreground}" TabStripPlacement="Top">
            <TabItem Header="tab1" Background="Transparent"   Template="{DynamicResource TabItemControlTemplate}"/>
            <TabItem Header="tab2" Background="Transparent" Template="{DynamicResource TabItemControlTemplate}"/>
            <TabItem Header="tab3" Background="Transparent" Template="{DynamicResource TabItemControlTemplate}"/>

    </TabControl>

</Grid>
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Isn't setting TabStripPlacement property working for you ?

Comment: Well it is working but i want to change it by pressing one of the buttons so setting the property alone wouldnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it out

```
<DockPanel>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button x:Name="btnTop" Click="btnTop_Click">Top</Button>
        <Button Name="btnRight" Click="btnRight_Click">Right</Button>
        <Button Name="btnBottom" Click="btnBottom_Click">Bottom</Button>
        <Button Name="btnLeft" Click="btnLeft_Click">Left</Button>
    </StackPanel>
    <TabControl Name="tabControl" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
    <TabItem Header="Tab1"></TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Tab2"></TabItem>
</TabControl>
</DockPanel>
```

In your code behind file

```
    private void btnTop_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        tabControl.TabStripPlacement = Dock.Top;
    }

    private void btnRight_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        tabControl.TabStripPlacement = Dock.Right;
    }

    private void btnBottom_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        tabControl.TabStripPlacement = Dock.Bottom;
    }

    private void btnLeft_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        tabControl.TabStripPlacement = Dock.Left;
    }
```

Comment: Another question...Hope i dont annoy you with it. If i would have to rotate the Header by 90° How would I do That. On ButtonClick Of Course.

Comment: No problem. There is RenderTransform property in which you can define RotateTransform. Read about it to get more info on that you will discover many ways to make best use of it in code.

Comment: Well I tried that and it worked perfect. Then i added some buttons only for this layout. The problem is with this trigger it always rotates the header when i put the TabStrip on thee right or left. Got some advice?